# Product stock is not saved when creating a product programmatically

Tags: product, stock, resource-model, save, cataloginventory

I'm creating products programatically on Magento CE 1.8.1. The form works fine except every once in a while we get a nasty error that comes and goes away, and does not affect all users.

```
:"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '970-1' 
for key 'UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID'"
```

Like I said, it doesn't always show up. I found many questions about this problem and saw as many suggestions to use

```
$product->getResource()->save($product);
// instead of 
// $product->save();
```

I tried that and I think the error does stop showing up, but a new problem arises; stock isn't saved properly. The code that I was using was:

```
// this works with $newProduct->save()
// but it doesn't work with $product->getResource()->save($newProduct)

$newProduct->setStockData(array(
              'qty'=>$params["qty"],
              'is_in_stock'=>1, 'notify_stock_qty'=>$params["stockqty"]));
```

I then tried using this:

```
$newProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
$stockItem->assignProduct($newProduct);
$stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
$stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
$stockItem->setData('use_config_notify_stock_qty', 0);
$stockItem->setData('qty', 40);
$newProduct->setStockItem($stockItem);
//save product..
```

But nothing. Stock is always 0, and `manage_stock` is always set to `No`. So I tried loading and saving the stock item *after* saving the product but I got a new error: `` "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bitnami_magento`.`cataloginventory_stock_item`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CATINV_STOCK_ITEM_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON D)" `` which sounds like the product hasn't been created yet! I checked the backend and the product *was* created, but with no stock. **It seems like the resource save method ignores the `stockData` and also the `stockItem`.**

I'm running out of ideas here. I've read a bunch of questions here where these worked but they're not working for me. Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: Have you checked this [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programatically-manually-creating-simple-magento-product/)? This might help.

Comment: Not a direct solution but I've had success with: https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport

Comment: @AdarshKhatri I have. Like I said, that code works but allows for the error to show up everyonce in a while. It is what I have though.

Comment: @B00MER Thanks, but this code is not for importing products. This is to allow certain users to create products from the frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example where you load the `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item` instance, you should save the instance itself instead of the product.

Saving the product doesn't work, because it ignores the assigned stock item. You can see why this is by looking at the the method

```
Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer::saveInventoryData
```

This method is triggered by the `catalog_product_save_after` event, which is called after a product is saved. The method first checks whether `stock_data` is set; if it is not set, the stock item is not updated.

Comment: I've tried this but I get an failed constraint exception. Apparently the product isn't already saved in the database when I try saving the stock item so the product Id constraint fails. I checked that I wasn't trying to save the stock item before the product existed and the code is in the right order so I can only assume the data base transaction hasnt been commited yet. I must be missing something

Comment: I'll give this another go. Maybe i find something I hadn't tried yet. This looks the most promissing

Comment: Good luck. I encountered this constraint violation a while ago when I was extending an import module with stock data. Unfortunately I cannot recall the exact cause anymore, but it turned out to be a bug in my code.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it seems like the best fit for my problem, but I did not implement this. I changed something in my code which appears to make this not necessary anymore but it's not an answer to this question; it's a different method. If no other answer arises before the bounty expires this one should receive the bounty points.

Comment: Is it that you don't need any stock updates at all anymore, or are you using the `setStockData` approach (which is my preferred choice when updating stock as part of updating a product)?

Comment: This is for creating new products. Existing products can be updated just fine. Its new products that won't save the stock data at all.

Comment: I just checked the code of my latest import module: regarding stock, I treat new and updated products the same. The only fields I need to update are `qty` and `is_in_stock`. Also, I made sure that `manage_stock` is set globally in the system configuration.

Comment: Yes, ``qty`` and ``is_in_stock`` work with ``$product->setStockData(...)->save()`` and it is what we have right now. It was just that I was getting that nasty constraint violation every now and then and was told not to call ``save()`` on the product object. But I added validation for duplicate SKUs (out of desperation mostly) and the error hasn't showed up again yet. It's worth noting that many different users with no relation between them could upload products separetly. I guess I was trying to fix my problem the wrong way.

Comment: Truth is, since the bug stopped showing up I'm no longer working on this and moved to different priorities so I haven't found the time to keep trying something different.

Answer (score 4):

This is a working example wich i use:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
                $product->setTypeId('simple');
                $product->setName('name');
                $product->setDescription('xyz');
                $product->setShortDescription('&nbsp;');
                $product->setStatus(1);
                $product->setTaxClassId(1);
                $product->setWeight(0);
                $product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'));
                $product->setManufacturer(1);
                $product->setAttributeSetId(1);
                $product->setSku('sku');
                $product->setPrice(5);
                $product->setVisibility(1);
                $product->save();
```

After saving the product create stock item:

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
            $stockItem->assignProduct($product);
            $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
            $stockItem->setData('stock_id', 1);
            $stockItem->setData('store_id', 1);
            $stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
            $stockItem->setData('use_config_manage_stock', 0);
            $stockItem->setData('min_sale_qty', 1);
            $stockItem->setData('use_config_min_sale_qty', 0);
            $stockItem->setData('max_sale_qty', 1000);
            $stockItem->setData('use_config_max_sale_qty', 0);
            $stockItem->setData('qty', 10);
            $stockItem->save();
```

Comment: Well, like I said in the question, the line ``$product-> save()`` makes that first error happen sometimes so I have to save via de resource class. I've already tried your code.

Answer (score 0):

Before saving the new stock data, try loading the stock item from the product, and deleting it.

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
    ->loadByProduct($product)
    ->delete();
```

Comment: The thing is the stock item doesn't even exist at this point. It is not saved when I call ``$product->getResource()->save($product)``. I checked the database for it and it's not there. That _is_ the problem :/